# Change the caller of a function dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have implemented 2 providers in the DAL of my application.

One is a Redis Cache provider and the other is a database provider.

```
public class CacheProvider : IProvider
{
    public List<int> GetCustomerIds()
    {
        return cache.GetCustomerIds();
    }
}

public class DBProvider : IProvider
{
    public List<int> GetCustomerIds()
    {
        return db.GetCustomerIds();
    }
}
```

I have implemented an interface for these

```
public interface IProvider
{
     List<int> GetCustomerIds();
}
```

I have the following situation.

If the cache function somehow fails or the cache expires while trying to execute I want to fall back and call the db version on the function.

There will be many functions implemented so I was thinking of creating a gateway where all functions will be passed as a parameter and if it fails fall back to the db version

```
public List<int> RunTheMethod(Func<int> myMethodName)
{
    // Run method from cache
    myMethodName()

    if method fails, run method from db
    myMethodName()
}
```

Is there a way to implement this sort of functionality? I know I may have to implement a few of these methods as the parameters will vary.

Comment: You've basically answered your own question! Normally I would have a service layer between my client/front end, this would check to see if an object or collection of objects were in the cache, if not I would then get from db and populate the cache. Also what do you mean by fail?

Comment: By fail I mean if the cache goes down or an error is encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, with a little reflection to make this work though I am not sure about the performance

We have *IDataProvider* which is implemented by the cache provider, the database provider and the 'Gateway' (I have included 3 methods in IDataProvider to show examples of different return / parameters and overloading)

The Gateway doesn't have to implement IDataProvider but doing so makes life a bit easier as the methods on the Gateway need to have the same signatures as those to be called on the providers.

The Gateway contains a list of IDataProviders and for each call it goes down through the list and attempts to execute. It returns the first success and throws an exception if none succeed.

The Execute<>() method is a quick way to wire everything up, we can just call it each time and let it handle matching with the methods on the IDataProviders and re-trying on failure.

For testing purposes I have created a way to force the first (caching provider) to fail.

```
interface IDataProvider {
        List<int> Method1();
        List<string> Method2(string parameter1);
        List<string> Method2(string parameter1, string parameter2);
}

class DataProvider1 : IDataProvider {

    private readonly string[] Strings = { "A", "B", "C" };

    private bool _callFails;

    public DataProvider1(bool callFails) {
        _callFails = callFails;
    }

    public List<int> Method1() {
        if (_callFails) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return new List<int>(){1,2,3};
    }

    public List<string> Method2(string parameter1) {
        if (_callFails) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return Strings.Select(s => s + parameter1).ToList();
    }

    public List<string> Method2(string parameter1, string parameter2) {

        if (_callFails) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return Strings.Select(s => s + parameter1 + parameter2).ToList();
    }

}

class DataProvider2 : IDataProvider {

    private readonly string[] Strings = { "D", "E", "F" };

    public List<int> Method1() {
        return new List<int>(){4,5,6};
    }

    public List<string> Method2(string parameter1) {
        return Strings.Select(s => s + parameter1).ToList();
    }

    // overload
    public List<string> Method2(string parameter1, string parameter2) {
        return Strings.Select(s => s + parameter1 + parameter2).ToList();
    }

}


class Gateway : IDataProvider {

    private readonly List<IDataProvider> _dataProviders;

    public Gateway(IEnumerable<IDataProvider> dataProviders) {
        _dataProviders = new List<IDataProvider>(dataProviders);
    }

    public List<int> Method1() {
        return Execute<List<int>>();
    }

    public List<string> Method2(string parameter1) {
        return Execute<List<string>>(parameter1);
    }

    public List<string> Method2(string parameter1, string parameter2) {
        return Execute<List<string>>(parameter1, parameter2);
    }


    private T Execute<T>(params object[] parameters) {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        MethodBase methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

        var methodInfo = typeof(IDataProvider).GetMethod(methodBase.Name, methodBase.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());

        var index = 0;

        while (index < _dataProviders.Count) {
            try {
                return(T)methodInfo.Invoke(_dataProviders[index], parameters);
            } catch (Exception) {

                index++;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("None of the methods succeeded");

    }
}
```

**Unit tests**

```
[TestClass]
public class DataProviderFixture {

    #region Create

    private Gateway Create(bool firstCallFails = false) {
        return new Gateway(new IDataProvider []{
            new DataProvider1(firstCallFails), 
            new DataProvider2()});
    }

    #endregion


    [TestMethod]
    public void ExecuteNoProblems() {

        var gateway = Create();
        var numbers = gateway.Method1();

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, numbers);

        var letters = gateway.Method2("1");

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "A1", "B1", "C1" }, letters);

        letters = gateway.Method2("1", "a");

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "A1a", "B1a", "C1a" }, letters);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ExecuteFirstCallFails() {

        var gateway = Create(true);
        var numbers = gateway.Method1();

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5, 6 }, numbers);

        var letters = gateway.Method2("2");

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "D2", "E2", "F2" }, letters);

        letters = gateway.Method2("1", "b");

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "D1b", "E1b", "F1b" }, letters);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Alan, I will implement this before the day is done and I will get back to you